# Change detection in setTimeout

Tags: angular

From what I have read, this should work pretty easily ([without any specific ngZone commands](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html)), but I'm not seeing that with my ngrx app.

I have this template

```
<app-resto
  [resto]='selectedResto'
  [idx]='selectedRestoIndex'
  (action)='action.next($event)'
  [@selectedResto]='selectedRestoState'>
</app-resto>
```

And this controller

```
ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('OUT:', this.selectedResto.qname);
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.selectedResto = this.restos[this.selectedRestoIndex];
        // this.selectedResto = Object.assign({}, this.restos[this.selectedRestoIndex]);

        console.log('IN:', this.selectedResto.qname);
    }, 500);
}
```

What I see is that when `selectedRestoIndex` changes, the rendering of that in `<app-resto>` takes place and OUT logs. Then IN is logged, but there is no further change to `<app-resto>`. Note how I have tried to force selectedResto to have a different Ref too.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set `changeDetectionStrategy` to `onPush` by any chance?

Comment: OMG - genius. I thought I could do that because I was using ngrx and one-way dataflow, but I guess have deviated from the pure along the way

Comment: `OnPush` is to be set only in 'dumb' components that do not specify any logic by themselves and are presentation-only.